# Regex expression for replacing content between two tags

Tags: regex, reactjs

I am building an reddit like application in ReactJs for learning purposes. I try to make a text area in which a user can enter a link through a button. The function will generate something like this: `[display]what_link_will_display[link]actual_link[\link][\display]other_text`. The purpose is when I render this particular text, will be converted into something like this: `<a href="actual_link">what_link_will_display<\a>other_text`. With my pretty low knowledges of RegEx I managed to achieve what I wanted using the expression:

```
\[display\](.*?)\[link\](.*?)\[\\link\]\[\\display\]
```

and the replacement:

```
<a href="$2">$1</a>
```

Although it works, at least while testing on [online js regex tool](https://www.venea.net/web/js_regexp_online_tester), the regex rule looks pretty silly to me and I'm not sure it works on all cases. Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: That is how you do it. --- *FYI:* For a better online JS Regex tool, try https://regex101.com/

Comment: Can there be any other `[display]` or `[link]` tags in between, where you have `.*?`?

Comment: No, these are the only tags. Thanks for responses!

Comment: So, it is already good as is.